# python Data Structure for card game without using classes

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Not sure how to store the name and stats of cards without using classes. I was thinking dictionaries but I can't seem to get the code to work. The names of the cards are imported from a text file and the statistics of the card are randomly generated. It only seems to iterate once rn instead of storing all the cards. Thanks for help!

```
def cardValueGen():
    cards = []
    cards.append(random.randint(1,5))
    cards.append(random.randint(1,100))
    cards.append(random.randint(1,10))
    cards.append(random.randint(1,10))
    return cards

completeCard = {}
def fileReader(numOfCards, completeCard): 
    lines = []#array that we place names of dogs into
    cards = []

    f = open("message.txt","r") # command to OPEN the text file

    for x in f: 
        #lines.append(x) 
        #cards.append(cardValueGen())
        completeCard["name:"] = [x]
        completeCard["name:"].append(cardValueGen())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a simple dictionary provided you have unique card names

```
import random
def cardValueGen():
    cards = []
    cards.append(random.randint(1,5))
    cards.append(random.randint(1,100))
    cards.append(random.randint(1,10))
    cards.append(random.randint(1,10))
    return cards

completeCards = {}
def fileReader(completeCards): 
    f = open("message.txt","r") # command to OPEN the text file

    for x in f: 
        completeCards[x] = cardValueGen()
    f.close()

fileReader(completeCards)
print(completeCards)
```

Comment: You should also `close` the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of doing this. One way it to make a list of the cards, but each card is a dict with two entries:

```py
def cardValueGen():
    cards = []
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 5))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 100))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 10))
    cards.append(random.randint(1, 10))
    return cards


def fileReader(completeCard): 
    with open("message.txt", "r") as f: #command to OPEN the text file
        for x in f: 
            card = {'name': x.strip()}
            card["values"] = cardValueGen()
            completeCard.append(card)

completeCard = []
fileReader(completeCard)
print(completeCard)
```

Comment: if each card has unique name then cant we put that as key and then the value as the return value of `cardValueGen` in a dict itself. That would allow faster access of card stats, Instead of searching entire list.

Comment: @AlbinPaul: Yes, that's right. As I said there are a number of ways of doing this. Perhaps you should write up that answer.

Comment: If each card is a dictionary, then the statistics might as well each be one dictionary entry, rather than have all the values in a very obscure list. `def cardGen(name): return {'name': name, 'speed': random.randint(1, 5), 'life': random.randint(1, 100), 'attack': random.randint(1, 10), 'defense': random.randint(1, 10)}`